# One-liner to create a dictionary with one entry

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a method which takes a `Dictionary<int, int>` as a parameter

```
public void CoolStuff(Dictionary<int, int> job)
```

I want to call that method with one dictionary entry, such as

```
int a = 5;
int b = 6;
var param = new Dictionary<int, int>();
param.Add(a, b);
CoolStuff(param);
```

How can I do it in one line?

Comment: Defining values of the object with the constructor is called an _object  initializer_.

For collections (like dictionary), it is called a _collection initializer_.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

This is it, if you do not need the `a` and `b` variables:

```
var param = new Dictionary<int, int> { { 5, 6 } };
```

or even

```
CoolStuff(new Dictionary<int, int> { { 5, 6 } });
```

Please, read [How to: Initialize a Dictionary with a Collection Initializer (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb531208.aspx)

Answer (score 13):

```
var param = new Dictionary<int, int>() { { 5, 6 } };
```